# DBT not upgrading in venv

Tags: upgrade, dbt

I am working to upgrade dbt from 0.17 to 1.0 in venv set up.
I made the changes in the dbt_project.yml file. When run dbt compile , I get an error
ERROR: Runtime Error
at path []: Additional properties are not allowed ('seed-paths', 'model-paths' were unexpected)

Can anyone suggest on how to fix this error?

I did run below command to upgrade dbt in venv but it does not upgrade and still shows older version on dbt --version

pip install \
dbt-core 
dbt-postgres 
dbt-redshift 
dbt-snowflake 
dbt-bigquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRzZH.png)

Answer (score 1):

I would additionally try `pip uninstall dbt` ahead of these commands.

Alternatively you might try adding the`--upgrade` flag to your command.

If that doesn’t work, perhaps `which dbt` will help you confirm whether the version that’s being triggered is inside/outside your virtualenv.